# How do I save multiple values in a single column in the database using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, rubygems

I want to save each modification of any database column. For example, if a user updates his/her contact info then my application should update value but also keep save previous value. How can I do it? Is there any gem available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PaperTrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to do this. You can selectively track database tables and also specify columns to exclude.

It is pretty well documented on the Github page, but basically to set it up all you have to do is (copied directly from the docs):

```
# Add PaperTrail to your Gemfile.
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 4.0.0'

# Add a versions table to your database.
bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install
bundle exec rake db:migrate

# Add has_paper_trail to the models you want to track.
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail Is a great resource for this.